# How to fix "java.io.IOException: read failed, socket might closed or timeout" when trying to connect to a paired device?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I've made a `ListView` with devices currently paired to my phone so that I can select one of them and connect to it. To determine which device was selected, I'm storing their MAC Addresses in an array so that I can get a device by its address. When I select a device, the app freezes for a bit then restores with no success of connecting. I cannot find the solution anywhere and I'm stuck. I'm still a beginner and do not understand much. An exception occurs that goes like:

```
java.io.IOException: read failed, socket might be closed or timeout, read ret: -1
```

Here is my code.

```
// If the UUID is incorrect then this one does not work as well
// 00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb

private static final UUID CONNECTION_UUID = UUID.fromString("0000110E-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");

public static boolean connectDevice(final int a) {

    try {
        BluetoothDevice mBluetoothDevice = btAdapter.getRemoteDevice(deviceAddress[a]);
        BluetoothSocket mBluetoothSocket = mBluetoothDevice.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(CONNECTION_UUID);
        btAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

        mBluetoothSocket.connect();

        mmOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(mBluetoothSocket.getOutputStream());
        mmInputStream = new DataInputStream(mBluetoothSocket.getInputStream());

        mBluetoothSocket.close();

    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: When you are connecting to another device, did you make sure that the bluetooth of that device is discoverable or not?

Comment: @ReazMurshed Yes, I've checked that again and it is discoverable.

Comment: Don't catch null pointer exceptioms. Fix the bugs in your code so they don't happen.

Comment: Can you please use the `CONNECTION_UUID = "8ce255c0-200a-11e0-ac64-0800200c9a66"`

Comment: Can you please try my solution and let me know if that works? Thanks :)

Comment: @user207421
I did it on purpose temporarily to make my code more readable, The method "connect" is being reached. It's confirmed by the exception in the detailed output log.

Comment: @ReazMurshed
I've tested that UUID before your answer then after your answer and it did not work. The one I already used in my code didn't work either but the one I commented did. Which is:
`00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb`

Comment: I continue to be shocked by this illiterate and inaccurate message. As can be seen from the accepted answer, it has nothing whatsoever to do with the actual cause. And socket closure is a completely different condition from connection timeout. The Android developers need to do something about it.

Comment: @user207421
It does have to do with the actual cause but It's my own fault for not emphasizing enough about it and its details. I am lucky to find ReazMurshed that took the problem the way it actually is blindfolded figuratively speaking. I apologize, I am taking practice on this site as best as I can.

Comment: According to the answer you accepted, the actual cause is lack of encryption. Not 'socket might closed', which it isn't, or 'timeout' either. And it's not your fault. My comment was directed at the Android developers, not at you. You reported what you saw accurately, and you didn't even put in the missing 'be'.

Comment: @user207421 Oh, my apologies! I thought I didn't give enough info as the detailed log in my debug window, even though usually people know the exception and possible solutions to it, therefore I avoid showing too much and keep the main code organized as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the `CONNECTION_UUID` that you provided in your code, I assume that you are connecting with a Bluetooth serial board. I am not sure about the problem yet, however, I thought of writing this answer to provide a probable solution that might solve your issue.

I think in case of the paired devices, you need to initiate the connection with a secure channel. Currently, you are using an insecure channel.

From the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html#createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(java.util.UUID))...

> The communication channel will not have an authenticated link key i.e
>   it will be subject to man-in-the-middle attacks. For Bluetooth 2.1
>   devices, the link key will be encrypted, as encryption is mandatory.
>   For legacy devices (pre Bluetooth 2.1 devices) the link key will be
>   not be encrypted. Use createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(UUID) if an
>   encrypted and authenticated communication channel is desired.

Hence you might consider using `createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord()` for your case.

Instead of this

```
BluetoothSocket mBluetoothSocket = mBluetoothDevice.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(CONNECTION_UUID);
```

Use this...

```
BluetoothSocket mBluetoothSocket = mBluetoothDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(CONNECTION_UUID);
```

I hope that solves your problem.

From the comment below - The UUID that actually worked here is `00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb`

Comment: Thank you a lot. That solved the problem. I'm not sure about the actual connection as you can tell in the code but that is my thing from now on. I've gotten rid of any exception which was my goal.

Comment: However, the only UUID that works is: `00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb`

Comment: That's great. I am very happy to help you. :)